Need help in Understanding the proof of Rouche's theorem
I have found proof of Rouche's theorem in various text and on different post on this site too.
But I am only interested in the proof given here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_Theorem
Everything went fine upto,
for brevity write $F=1+\frac{g}{f}$
But after this, I am having trouble in understanding the proof.
(1) They said, As $|\frac{g}{f}|<1$ on $\gamma$, hence we must have $|Re(\frac{g}{f})|<1$ But, how?
(Is this because, for any complex number $x+iy$ we have $|Re(x+iy)|≤|x+iy|$?)
(2) From above they conclude that, $0<|Re(F)|<2$ on $\gamma$ How?
(3) From the (2) they conclude that, image of $\gamma$ under $F$ does not encircle $0$ How?
(4) They write, $\frac{1}{2πi}\oint_\gamma \frac{F'(z)}{F(z)} \,dz =\frac{1}{2πi}\oint_{F(\gamma)} \frac{1}{z} \,dz $ How?
Please help me. I am not getting (2), (3) & (4).

$Re(F)=1+Re(g/f)$, then use triangle inequality to get (2), if the real part of $F$ is never touching zero, then it cannot encircle 0.  The last is a change of variable $w=F(z)$.

@Yimin  please can you explain in details. I am not getting it. Further, how is last is change of variable? They had taken integral around different curves? On the left it is $\gamma$ whereas on right it is $F(\gamma) $

triangle inequality gives you $0 \le 1 - |Re(g/f)|\le |1 + Re(g/f)|\le 1 + |Re(g/f)| \le 2$. If the image of $F(\gamma)$ encircles origin, then some point on the image must be on the left side of the origin, that is, negative real value, which contradicts with (2).

(1): Given: $|g(z)| < |f(z)|$ for $z \in \gamma$.  So $\frac{|g(z)|}{|f(z)|} < 1$ there.  The inequation $|g/f| < 1$ says $g/f$ is in the open disk centered at $0$ of radius $1$.  All points on that disk have real part in $(-1,1)$, so ...
(2): $g/f$ is in the open disk centered at $0$ of radius $1$, so $F = 1+f/g$ is in the open disk centered at $1$ of radius $1$.  All points on that disk have real part in $(0,2)$.
(3): For a path to encircle the origin, it has to pass through the imaginary axis (at least once, possibly several times).  That is, it has to have real part zero.  $F$ never has zero real part.
(4): $u$-substition.  Let $u = F(z)$, so $\mathrm{d}u = F'(z)\,\mathrm{d}z$, and the $u$ path is $F(\gamma)$ ...
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}} \oint_{\gamma} \; \frac{F'(z)}{F(z)} \,\mathrm{d}z  &  \\
\text{let } u = F(z)  & \text{, }  \mathrm{d}u = F'(z) \,\mathrm{d}z \text{, and} \\
z \in \gamma \rightarrow {} & u \in F(\gamma)  \\
= \frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\oint_{F(\gamma)} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u}
\end{align*}
and this is literally the definition of the winding number of the path $F(\gamma)$ around the origin.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number#Complex_analysis for a statement that literally includes this form.

Sir, can you add details about (4)

@GeneralMathematics : There's essentially nothing to add.  I've written it as I would expect an undergraduate to think about it, but there is little more to say...

sir, thank you so much, for replying and for the wonderful answer.
